# pass metadata through stripe checkout session node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I have this below:

```
app.get('/create-checkout-session', async (req, res) => {
    let customer = {
        price: req.query.price,
        quantity: req.query.quantity,
        page: req.query.page,
        email: req.query.email,
        name: req.query.name
    }


    let successurl = 'http://localhost:1111/' + customer.page + ''
    let failedurl = 'http://localhost:1111/' + customer.page + ''
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ['card'],
    customer_email: customer.email,
    line_items: [
      {
        price_data: {
          currency: 'cad',
          product_data: {
            name: customer.page
          },
          unit_amount: customer.price,
        },
        quantity: customer.quantity,
      },
    ],
    payment_intent_data: {
      metadata: {
        'desc': customer.page
      }
    },
    mode: 'payment',
    success_url: successurl,
    cancel_url: failedurl,
  })

  res.redirect(303, session.url);
});
```

I tried to pass the `metadata`, but it doesn't work at all. It says empty when i get the object back after.
i've never had this before, and can't really figure out what's wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Specifically which object are your expecting to see the `metadata` field on in the response? You're passing your `metadata` hash under the [`payment_intent_data`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-metadata) parameter, which means it'll be set on the underlying Payment Intent of the Checkout Session. If you want the metadata to be set on the Checkout Session object then you should instead use the root [`metadata`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-metadata) field on creation.

Comment: @JonathanSteele sorry for responsing so late. I am trying to get be able to access the metadata fields after the checkout session is finished. so if i try to return all the customers in stripe, it should return the metadata with the field `desc` in it.

Comment: @JonathanSteele i dont need to set it under the payment_intent_data, but i was just trying different things. so far, nothing works

Comment: Unfortunately there's no direct way to attach metadata from a Checkout Session directly to the associated Customer object. You'd need to handle this logic yourself by calling the [update the customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/update#update_customer-metadata) endpoint.